# Center a rotated Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, geometry, transform

I am working on a rotation of a child within parent. Parent is fixed width and height whereas child's width and height is dynamic.

Lets say,

```
Child width - Cw
Child height - Ch
Parent width - Pw
Parent height - Ph


When `Cw > Pw && Ch < Ph` then expected: `left=0 and vertically centered`
When `Cw < Pw && Ch > Ph` then expected: `top=0 and horizontally centered`
When `Cw > Pw && Ch > Ph` then expected: `left=0 and top=0`
When `Cw < Pw && Ch < Ph` then expected: `vertically and horizontally centered`
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Xja29/1/

I have attempted a lot in last few days. One of the fiddle where I was doing is here. Just incase you don't believe - http://jsfiddle.net/zgvEC/50/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TTGCh/ check this out #e: aw, the height is messed up

Answer (score 0):

Have you though about approaching this slightly differently and using CSS for the rotation, and jQuery for the start/stop action? The below is only a shell example for you to see how it may be applied for your purposes.

Like **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QWG7t/2/)**

CSS

```
div{
    display:inline-block;
}
.parent{
    border:1px solid grey;
}
.child{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border-radius:9px;
    background:blue;
    margin:10px;
}

.rotate {
    -webkit-animation:rotate 4s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:rotate 4s linear infinite;
    animation:rotate 4s linear infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes rotate { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes rotate { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes rotate { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

HTML

```
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'>
    </div>    
</div>
<a id='rotate' href='#'>Rotate</a>
```

jQuery

```
$('#rotate').click(function(){
   $('.child').addClass('rotate');
});
```